# How to encase words with quotations?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am currently trying to convert a list of 1000 words into this format:

'known', 'buss', 'hello',
and so on.

The list i have is currently in this format:

known
worry
claim
tenuous
porter

I am trying to use notepad++ to do this, if anybody could point me in the correct direction, that would be great!

Answer (score 2):

Use this if you want a comma delimited list but no extra comma at the end.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(\S+)(\s+)?`
- Replace with: `'$1'(?2,:)`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(\S+)       # group 1, 1 or more non spaces
(\s+)?      # group 2, 1 or more spaces, optional
```

**Replacement:**

```
'$1'        # content of group 1 enclosed in quotes
(?2,:)      # if group 2 exists, add a comma, else, do nothing
```

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @8au: You're welcome, glad it helps, feel free to mark the answer as accepted, [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

How about replacing `(\S+)` with `'$1'`? Make sure your Regular Expression button is selected in the Find and Replace tool inside Notepad++

**Explanation**

`(\S+)` is regex for repeating non-whitespace characters (1 or more). Wrapping it in parenthesis puts it in a capture group which can be accessed in numerical order by using a dollar sign (`$1`).

`'$1'` will take that found text from the Find above and replace it with capture group #1 (`$1`) wrapped in single quotes `'`.

**Sample**

Input: `known worry claim tenuous porter`

Output: `'known' 'worry' 'claim' 'tenuous' 'porter'`

Comment: The OP wanted commas

Comment: Thanks so much! :)